# being usages dilemma

Tags: grammar, prepositions, grammaticality

I've read in BBC that we use use "being" as a verb-ing. BBC has listed two kind of usage, What I want to learn here is about "preposition+verb-ing" form of usage.It has been said that "being+past particle" here is functioning as nouns. But I don't know what kind of meanings it would conveys. So,The following are two examples from BBC

1. I look forward to being interviewed on the current affairs programme. ( what does "being interviewed" mean? )
2. She was afraid of being accused of a crime which she did not commit. (What does" being accused of" mean ?)
   [Learning English | BBC World Service](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv197.shtml)
   I think the following are also the examples of "preposition+verb-ing":
   -John talks about being helped by a stranger. (Does it mean -john talks about that he was helped by a stranger.)

-Before being moved to an apartment, he lived in a hostel.
(Does it mean "Before he was moved to........)

-Despite being helped by nurse,he slepped and fell. (Does it mean- despite he was helped by nurse ,........)

-What is the risk of being killed in war ? (Does it mean--what is the risk of killing in a war ?)

-What are the chances of being killed by a falling tree ? (Does it mean: what are the chances of killing in a war?)

-Share your experiences of being helped by a teacher. (Does it mean: share your experiences when you were helped by a stranger ?)

**I am looking forward to him being interviewed** vs **I am looking forward  him to be interviewed.** Are these sentences same, if not what is the difference ??

I'm really confused.

Please explain me the meaning and usage of "being+past particle" when we use with "preposition" ?

Answer (score 0):

A form of *be* with a past participle is the normal way of forming a passive in English.

So *being interviewed* is the *-ing* form of *be interviewed*, which is the passive of *interview*.

*I look forward to being interviewed* means roughly the same as *I look forward to somebody interviewing me*.

*She was afraid of being accused of a crime which she did not commit* means roughly the same as *She was afraid of somebody accusing her of a crime which she did not commit*.

*I am looking forward to him being interviewed* (which most people regard as grammatical, though some complain that *him* should be *his* in that construction) means something very different from *I am looking forward to being interviewed*; because that last sentence means that it is me that is going to be interviewed.

*I am looking forward him to be interviewed* is not grammatical, because *looking forward to* cannot take an infinitive clause. This is not predictable from its meaning: it just happens to be an arbitrary fact about it. The word *expect*, which has a meaning somewhat similar to *look forward* (though not exactly the same) can take a to-infinitive clause, so *I am expecting him to be interviewed* is grammatical.  (Note that *to* plays a different role in the  two cases: with *looking forward* it is a preposition introducing the complement of the adjectival phrase. With *expect* it introduces a to-infinitive).